# "few and far between" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms, inversion

I checked the dictionary for the meaning of this expression. It means "not very many or not appearing very frequently".

Can anybody decompose this structure and justify why the expression gets this meaning? Especially, what is the "far between" part meaning here?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This sentence:

> In the desert, gas stations are few and far between.

means that there are few gas stations in the desert, and there is a lot of space between any two gas stations. In other words, there are few gas stations and they are widely dispersed. **Far between** refers to the distance between the gas stations.

I'm a native speaker, and I found this expression confusing for many years. But it does make sense.

Comment: That's a good example of how the expression can be completely literal. Figurative meanings (e.g. "honest politicians are few and far between") then follow from that. +1

Answer (score 2):

Checking other dictionaries might have helped you better! :)

The [FreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/few+and+far+between) has an entry for that:

> few and far between: *very few; few and **widely scattered**.*

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/few-and-far-between):

> ***at great intervals; widely spaced***

Yes, it *does* talk about having distances as well.